# Storing datasets and intermediary files in Amazon EC2

Tags: r, amazon-ec2

I'd like to use Amazon EC2 to work with large datasets  in R.

I have launched an instance, installed R, and created an EBS image of the volume "root" in a drive of 300 Go, unchecking "Delete on Termination".

I then started this AMI in a new instance, uploaded some datasets to it, and terminated the instance.

When I launched this AMI later on a new instance, the hard drive was in the same state than when I first created the AMI - but I expected the uploaded datasets to be available. Is it expected behavior? If yes, what's the best way to store datasets and intermediate files between two connexions to Amazon EC2?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to configure  an EC2 AMI to store some datasets, not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use S3 as a filesystem.

Create an S3 bucket on AWS. In this example we're using the AWS command line utilities running locally:

```
aws s3 mb s3://bucketxyz
```

Then launch an EC2 instance. This example worked for Amazon Linux. `ssh` into the box, setup s3fs:

```
sudo yum install git gcc libstdc++-devel gcc-c++ fuse fuse-devel curl-devel libxml2-devel openssl-devel mailcap automake

git clone git://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse.git
cd s3fs-fuse/
./autogen.sh

./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

... and then setup your AWS credentials:

```
echo '[AWS Access Key ID]:[AWS Secret Access Key]' | sudo tee /etc/passwd-s3fs
sudo chmod 400 /etc/passwd-s3fs
```

Then mount the drive as a folder:

```
sudo mkdir /bucketxyz
sudo s3fs bucketxyz /bucketxyz
```

This folder is now accessible like any other folder, but resides in S3 and is therefore persistent and could be accessed from other instances if necessary.